# moment.js - isValid() возвращает false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var test = moment("2018-11-14T06:00:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm");
test.isValid(); // false
```

почему не валидное значение? Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var test = moment("2018-11-14T06:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(test.isValid());
console.log(typeof test, test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```